# How to properly display a focus rectangle in a compact SplitView menu item

Tags: windows-10, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm building my first Universal Windows Platform (UWP) App and am trying to implement the popular "Hamburger Menu" using the SplitView class.

Inspired by [many](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2015/04/implementing-hamburger-button-with.html) [samples](http://igrali.com/2015/04/12/getting-started-with-splitview-control-in-universal-apps/), the items hosted on the [`SplitView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.splitview.aspx) pane are re-styled [`RadioButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.radiobutton.aspx) controls, with a vertical highlight-rectangle, an icon and a text. The appearance is similar to that of the Groove app.

I'm now trying to implement navigation and selection using the keyboard, and this now bring a little focus-rect around the items in the `SplitView` pane. However, since the pane clips its contents when its [`DisplayMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.splitviewdisplaymode.aspx) is either `CompactInline` or `CompactOverlay`, the focus rectangle is also clipped, which is not the behavior a user would expect.

[image: A compact hamburger menu that displays a clipped rectangle around the currently focused menu item.]

Please, can anyone advise on how to property display the focus rectangle in this situation ?

Comment: how did you get the vertical highlight-rectangle? Could you send me a quick sample or link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an idea, what if you set the width of all radio button's to be same as the [CompactPaneLength](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.splitview.compactpanelength.aspx) property of SplitView. The default is 48 DIPs.

Comment: Yes, why not... Would you elaborate on how to do that? From the code behind, change the width depending upon the current DisplayMode of the SplitView ? That seems ugly but it might work. I was wondering if I was missing something builtin.

Comment: Right, from the code-behind or using adaptive trigger and visual states in xaml only. Check out this article: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/developers/articles/week03aug15/designing-with-adaptive-triggers-for-windows-10/